# Issues with iPhone 4 with music, apps, photos, etc.

Tags: itunes, iphone, data-synchronization, data-transfer, contacts

My iPhone 4 has never been synced to a computer but has music and stuff on it.  I'm scared that if I sync it to my new computer I'll lose my contacts, music, etc.  Does anyone know what happens when this is done?

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no problem in syncing your iPhone with your new computer: your data will just get copied onto the desktop, but will stay intact on your device.

Comment: And even if the data on your iPhone would get deleted, a warning would pop up first.